# how to install a new keyboard layout on mac when i don't have root access?

Tags: mac, keyboard-layout

i want to install a bepo keyboard on a mac where i study, but i don't have the root access so i can't install it in `/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts`, i thought i could install it in something like `~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts` but it doesn't exist, there is a `/Library/Keyboard/` folder but it doesn't change anything if i put my keyboard.bundle inside

do you know if it's possible to install a new keyboard layout without superuser rights on mac ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok my bad it was easy enough to solve... i just had to create the folder `~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/` and put my layout.bundle inside and restart.